# Problem with second counter in Javascript stopwatch

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let seconds = 00;
  let tens = 00;
  let mins = 00;

  let appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
  let appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
  let appendMins = document.getElementById("mins");

  //Initializing Buttons for functioning of engine

  let startButton = document.getElementById("start-btn");

  let stopButton = document.getElementById("stop-btn");

  let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-btn");

  let intervals;

  startButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervals);

    intervals = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
  };

  stopButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervals);
  };

  resetButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervals);

    tens = "00";

    seconds = "00";

    mins = "00";

    appendTens.innerHTML = tens;

    appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;

    appendMins.innerHTML = mins;
  };

  //main timer starts here

  function startTimer() {
    tens++;

    //defining how the timer counts when tens are less than 9

    if (tens <= 9) {
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
    }

    if (tens > 9) {
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
    }

    if (tens > 60) {
      /* console.log(seconds) */
      seconds++;

      appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;

      tens = 0;

      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
    }

    //defining how timer counts under the seconds

    //when seconds are less than or equal to 10

    if (seconds <= 9) {
      appendSeconds.innerTextML = "0" + seconds;
    }

    if (seconds > 9) {
      appendSeconds.innerTextML = seconds;
    }

    //when seconds exceed 60 it will converted to minutes

    if (seconds > 60) {
      mins++;

      appendMins.innerHTML = "0" + mins;

      seconds = 0;

      appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p><span id="mins">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>

</div>

<div class="btn-box">
  <button id="start-btn">Start</button>
  <button id="stop-btn">Stop</button>
  <button id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</div>
```

i have created a javascript stop watch but the problem is when second gets less than 10 the tenth digit of second counter gets disappear

i have created a javascript stop watch but the problem is when second gets less than 10 the tenth digit of second counter gets disappear

Comment: You have mistakenly put appendSeconds.innerTextML as opposed to innerHTML or innerText for the first two if seconds statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few issues:

1. Hundredths of seconds (which is oddly named `tenths` in your code) should only reset once they are above 99, not 60
2. Instead of making your own logic to pad the numbers, use [`.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) instead. Your logic was wrong, but using `.padStart()` fixes it and is the recommended way.
3. In your reset handler, you should reset the variables to numbers, not strings, because they were originally numbers.

See this code below:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let seconds = 0;
  let tens = 0;
  let mins = 0;

  let appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
  let appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
  let appendMins = document.getElementById("mins");

  //Initializing Buttons for functioning of engine

  let startButton = document.getElementById("start-btn");
  let stopButton = document.getElementById("stop-btn");
  let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-btn");

  let intervals;

  startButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervals);

    intervals = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
  };

  stopButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervals);
  };

  resetButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervals);

    tens = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    mins = 0;
    
    appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
    appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    appendMins.innerHTML = mins;
  };

  //main timer starts here

  function startTimer() {
    tens++;
    appendTens.innerHTML = tens.toString().padStart(2, '0');

    if (tens > 99) {
      seconds++;
      tens = 0;
      appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    }

    //when seconds exceed 60 it will converted to minutes
    if (seconds > 60) {
      mins++;
      seconds = 0;
      appendMins.innerHTML = mins.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p><span id="mins">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>.<span id="tens">00</span></p>

</div>

<div class="btn-box">
  <button id="start-btn">Start</button>
  <button id="stop-btn">Stop</button>
  <button id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have redone your conde to look and work a bit better, you can plug in this code into your code and bind them with your HTML elements.

```
let timeDivisions = ['3600000', '6000', '100', '1'];
let timeDivisionsLables = ['Number of Hours', 'Number of Minutes', 'Number of Seconds' , 'Number of Miliseconds'];
let milliSeconds = 3606101;
    timeDivisions.forEach((e,index)=>{
       
        if(milliSeconds >= e){
            
            console.log(` ${timeDivisionsLables[index]}  ${Math.floor( milliSeconds / e)}`);
            milliSeconds =  Math.floor( milliSeconds % e);
        }
        
    });
```